# Oddness with unittest in Python 3.8 - not detecting tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

This is a very odd issue, but `unittest` in Python is not actually picking up tests in the Test Case.

This is the code I'm working with, both the function I'm testing and the unittest code I'm trying to utilize in the `tests.py` script:

```
import unittest
import bs4


# This is the function we're testing
def zerolength_link_test(post_contents: str) -> bool:
    # Returns 'True' if there is a zero length link in here.
    bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(post_contents, 'html.parser')
    for link in bs.find_all('a'):
        if '<img ' in str(link):
            # Image embeds in links are not zero-length for this case.
            continue
        if len(link.text) == 0:
            return True
        if link.text.isspace() or not link.text.isprintable():
            return True

    return False


class ZeroLengthLinkTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def whitespace_only_link(self):
        test = 'This is a test at <a href="https://google.com"> </a> whitespace-only ' \
               'links which are effectively zero-length.'
        self.assertTrue(zerolength_link_test(test))

    def zero_length_link_nonobfuscated(self):
        test = "This is a test of <a href='google.com'></a> actual zero-length link text."
        self.assertTrue(zerolength_link_test(test))

    def zero_length_link_tag_obfuscation(self):
        test = "This is a test of <a href='google.com'><em></em></a> z" \
               "ero length links obfuscated by tags."
        self.assertTrue(zerolength_link_test(test))

    def unprintable_only_link(self):
        test = "This one has unprintable characters <a href='google.com'>\t\f\r\n</a> in the link."
        self.assertTrue(zerolength_link_test(test))

    def not_zero_length_link(self):
        test = "This is a test of <a href='https://google.com'>an actual link to " \
               "Google</a> that is not Zero Length."
        self.assertFalse(zerolength_link_test(test))

    def whitespace_only_link_tag_obfuscation(self):
        test = "This is a test of a whitespace only link <a href='google.com'><span> </span></a>" \
               " obfuscated with span tags."
        self.assertTrue(zerolength_link_test(test))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Unfortunately, when I run this, the system says "0 tests run" which suggests it's not able to find the test cases, and in turn is being fubar.

This is system Python 3 on Ubuntu 20.04 (3.8.2), but also tested with a local install of 3.8.5 (installed via pyenv in userspace).

Other test suites I've written in the past run fine with this, and are set up in a similar manner.

Am I doing something wrong with writing my `unittest` driven tests, or is this something quirky on this system only would you say?

Comment: I think that each of your test methods should be named: `test_* `.

Answer (score 2):

[Tests should start with `test` prefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example):

> The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters test. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.

```
import unittest
import bs4


# This is the function we're testing
def zerolength_link_test(post_contents: str) -> bool:
    # Returns 'True' if there is a zero length link in here.
    bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(post_contents, 'html.parser')
    for link in bs.find_all('a'):
        if '<img ' in str(link):
            # Image embeds in links are not zero-length for this case.
            continue
        if len(link.text) == 0:
            return True
        if link.text.isspace() or not link.text.isprintable():
            return True

    return False


class ZeroLengthLinkTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_whitespace_only_link(self):
        test = 'This is a test at <a href="https://google.com"> </a> whitespace-only ' \
               'links which are effectively zero-length.'
        self.assertTrue(zerolength_link_test(test))

    def test_zero_length_link_nonobfuscated(self):
        test = "This is a test of <a href='google.com'></a> actual zero-length link text."
        self.assertTrue(zerolength_link_test(test))

    def test_zero_length_link_tag_obfuscation(self):
        test = "This is a test of <a href='google.com'><em></em></a> z" \
               "ero length links obfuscated by tags."
        self.assertTrue(zerolength_link_test(test))

    def test_unprintable_only_link(self):
        test = "This one has unprintable characters <a href='google.com'>\t\f\r\n</a> in the link."
        self.assertTrue(zerolength_link_test(test))

    def test_not_zero_length_link(self):
        test = "This is a test of <a href='https://google.com'>an actual link to " \
               "Google</a> that is not Zero Length."
        self.assertFalse(zerolength_link_test(test))

    def test_whitespace_only_link_tag_obfuscation(self):
        test = "This is a test of a whitespace only link <a href='google.com'><span> </span></a>" \
               " obfuscated with span tags."
        self.assertTrue(zerolength_link_test(test))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Bluh I feel stupid now.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem pal @ThomasWard happens to every programmer sometime in life